# How to remove nautilus and intstall nautilus elementary with coverflow?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus-elementary

I'm on 11.04 64bit and want to change my default file manager from nautilus to nautilus elementary via PPA to keep it (Elementary) regularly updated.

I always want to know if Gloobus coverflow and preview works in 11.04 and if it works steps involved? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [nautilus-elementary PPA](https://launchpad.net/~am-monkeyd/+archive/nautilus-elementary-ppa) has been upgraded for the 11.04 release. Simply add the following PPA and upgrade ([graphical PPA instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Coverflow is incorporated into nautilus-elementary. Just press `F4`. gloobus-preview packages are provided in that same PPA.

Comment: Will your answer automatically remove nautilus and install nautilus-elementary or upgrade nautilus to nautilus-elementary. Thanks very much for your answer

Comment: nautilus is automatically upgraded to nautilus-elementary.